# How to fill missing values by next day value in multi-index Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
                    stock   price
symbol  DATE        
ABC     2014-01-02  000001  6
        2014-01-03  000001  7
        2014-01-06  000001  8
XYZ     2015-07-02  000002  9
        2015-07-04  000002  10
        2015-07-06  000002  11
```

I want to get a new dataframe as

```
                    stock   price
symbol  DATE        
ABC     2014-01-02  000001  6
        2014-01-03  000001  7
        2014-01-04  000001  8
        2014-01-05  000001  8
        2014-01-06  000001  8
XYZ     2015-07-02  000002  9
        2015-07-03  000002  10
        2015-07-04  000002  10
        2015-07-05  000002  11
        2015-07-06  000002  11
```

How to do it?

Comment: Are you grouping by the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), x.index.max(), name='DATE')).bfill()
df = df.reset_index(level=0).groupby(['symbol','stock'])['price'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  symbol   stock       DATE price
0    ABC  000001 2014-01-02     6
1    ABC  000001 2014-01-03     7
2    ABC  000001 2014-01-04     8
3    ABC  000001 2014-01-05     8
4    ABC  000001 2014-01-06     8
5    XYZ  000002 2015-07-02     9
6    XYZ  000002 2015-07-03    10
7    XYZ  000002 2015-07-04    10
8    XYZ  000002 2015-07-05    11
9    XYZ  000002 2015-07-06    11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `resample`, combined with `asfreq` on the grouping - the assumption here is that the `DATE` column is of datetime dtype:

```
(df
.reset_index('symbol')
.groupby('symbol')
.resample('1D')
.asfreq()
.drop(columns='symbol')
.bfill()
)


                    stock  price
symbol DATE                    
ABC    2014-01-02    1.0    6.0
       2014-01-03    1.0    7.0
       2014-01-04    1.0    8.0
       2014-01-05    1.0    8.0
       2014-01-06    1.0    8.0
XYZ    2015-07-02    2.0    9.0
       2015-07-03    2.0   10.0
       2015-07-04    2.0   10.0
       2015-07-05    2.0   11.0
       2015-07-06    2.0   11.0
```